# move legend in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I need to move the legend [image] in the south east, now is in the north east. I'd like to move it in the south east. It doesn't move from there, whatever I write.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot,
xmin=0, xmax=50, xlabel={$[lbs/min]$}, ylabel={Pressure Ratio},
ymin=0,ymax=4.5,width=1\textwidth]

\addplot[black,only marks,mark=+] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/185000_rpm.txt};      \label{imported_data}
\addplot[black,dashed,mark=dashed] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/greitzer_unstable.txt};\label{greitzer_unstable}
\addplot[black,mark=.] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/greitzer_stable.txt};                \label{greitzer_stable}

\end{axis}
\node[anchor=north east, draw=black,fill=white] (legend) at(plot.north east) {\begin{tabular}{l l l}
   unstable & \ref{greitzer_unstable}\\
   stable& \ref{greitzer_stable}\\
   imported data & \ref{imported_data}
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\textit{Caratteristica del GTX2860R approssimata con il polinomio di Moore-Greitzer, per $N=185000$}}
\label{fig:caratteristica_GTX2860R_approssimata}

\end{figure}
```

I also like to change the size of the tabular if possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you already try with `\node[anchor=south east, draw=black,fill=white] (legend) at(plot.south east)`? Can't test, since I can't compile your code due to the external files. Therefore, please prepare a self-contained, compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)  and add it to your question.

Comment: thanks, it works great. My mistake was in only changing the first south east. I would also like to change the size iff possible.

Comment: What size exactly? The font size, distances,...? Please clarify.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you give a fully compilable code?

Comment: here's a compliable code (I put 3 randoms equations)

Comment: You must edit the question (by clicking on the edit button) and not put the code in the answer area since it is not an answer.

Comment: Please also add the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: You might want to use `\addlegendentry` and `legend pos`.

Answer (score 1):

The inputs to the chart/graph are not available so the output is also not shown---however since the question regrading positioning the legend--just use the `at={(5,1)}` to pass the coordinates--and place it with the options in the legend style `\node[draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2pt, at={(5,1)}]`--the coord `5,1` can be varied to your choice to place the legend--this is an alternative to positioning using `north, south`etc

The `5,1` is only an approximation and can be varied to read `5.1,1.2`for example--`5.1` is the movement along the x-axis and `1.2` is the movement along the y-axis

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=-5,ymax=5,name=border]
\end{axis}

\node[draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2pt, at={(5,1)}]  {%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&black\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[red] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&red\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[green] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&green\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&blue
\end{tabular}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```